# Redirect http to https and www to non-www in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

First of all, I know there are lots of answers on this, but I don't actually find one that works. This is what I have in the `.htaccess` file right now, and I want to mention that it worked previously, but it does not anymore.

```
Redirect 301 /unt-de-cacao-de-plaja/filtre/producator/crisnatur/ /ingrijire-corporala/unt-cacao/unt-de-cacao-pentru-plaja-100g

Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "(?i)((\.tpl|\.ini|\.log|(?<!robots)\.txt))">
 Require all denied
## For apache 2.2 and older, replace "Require all denied" with these two lines :
# Order deny,allow
# Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
# If your opencart installation does not run on the main web folder make sure you folder it does run in ie. / becomes /shop/

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=extension/feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

# FORCE HTTPS AND NON WWW
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

As a mention, I will have a lot of Redirect 301 from old pages to the new ones since the entire structure has been changed.

And the links that I am redirecting inside my website come with "www" like:

```
https://www.example.com/unt-de-cacao-de-plaja/filtre/producator/crisnatur/
```

and needs to be redirected to:

```
https://example.com/ingrijire-corporala/unt-cacao/unt-de-cacao-pentru-plaja-100g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Redirect to https and non-www**

To instead redirect all requests to https and non-www, use the following code instead of the previous:

## Canonical HTTPS/non-WWW

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

As before, place this code in the root .htaccess of your site. Here is what it's doing:

- Checks if mod_rewrite is available
- Checks if HTTPS is off, or if the request includes www
- If either condition matches, the request qualifies and is redirected 
  to the https/non-www address

**OR**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, your explanation fixed the issue with https non-www redirect!

Comment: @Daniel. I will always help needed person. you can see my all answers. it's a very easy understanding and very useful for you. great thanks to upvote and remark my answer. see all here https://stackoverflow.com/users/8308674/mujahid-bhoraniya?tab=answers

Comment: This answer fails to address that the canonical redirect is in the wrong place in the config file. Even if you "correct" the directives, you still need to move the directives to before the front-controller, otherwise it simply won't redirect the majority of the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

A few issues, in order of importance:

1. You have your canonical HTTP to HTTPS and www to non-www redirects at the end of the file. By placing it at the end of the file, after your *front-controller*, it's simply never going to be processed for most requests. **This needs to be near the start of the `.htaccess` file, *before* your front-controller**.
2. You should avoid mixing redirects from both mod_alias (`Redirect`) and mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) in the same scope. Different modules execute at different times throughout the request, despite their apparent order in the config file. Since mod_rewrite is required for other redirects, you should convert the mod_alias `Redirect` directives to use `RewriteRule` instead.

   For example:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^unt-de-cacao-de-plaja/filtre/producator/crisnatur/$ /ingrijire-corporala/unt-cacao/unt-de-cacao-pentru-plaja-100g [R=301,L]
   ```
3. You should include the canonical scheme and hostname in your URL redirects in order to avoid multiple redirects when requesting an "old" URL at a non-canonical scheme ot hostname.

   For example:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^unt-de-cacao-de-plaja/filtre/producator/crisnatur/$ https://example.com/ingrijire-corporala/unt-cacao/unt-de-cacao-pentru-plaja-100g [R=301,L]
   ```
4. Depending on what you mean exactly by "a lot of Redirect 301" - you should not be doing this at all in `.htaccess` and instead redirecting in your server-side script, once you have determined that the request will 404. This is to prioritise normal site visiters and not your redirects (that get executed on every single request).

---

> ```
> RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Since you stated that these directives worked previously then I assume the use of the `HTTPS` *environment* variable is OK on your system. But note that, whilst this is relatively common, it's *non-standard*. (It implies the server is using some kind of SSL front-end/proxy.)

Note that the order of these rules will result in a double redirect when requesting `http://www.example.com/<anything>` (HTTP + www). Which is necessary if you are implementing [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), but otherwise, you should reverse these two rules to avoid this unnecessary double redirect.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this helped me understand how the redirects should actually work.

Comment: Since you've accepted the other answer, presumably `%{ENV:HTTPS}` was a problem after all? Although you had stated, "that it worked previously, but it does not anymore"? So, is this something that had changed?